# Big O of pre order traversal, in order traversal ,post order, level order for tree

Tags: big-o

Please let me know the Big Oh of the above.

Comment: Wouldn't the time complexity depend on the type of tree? Could you elaborate on that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how an **algorithm** executing these traversals would look like - **what data structure** would you use (stack, queue, something else?) and **how many operations** would you need to execute for processing each node in the tree? Would you ever have to process a node in the tree twice at all?