# Getting sibling value of key in a JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript, key-value, object-literal, siblings, cross-reference

Does anybody know of there's a way to reference the value of a sibling key in a JavaScript object literal?

so use the value of `target` in the `beforeNext()` function here:

```
obj: {
        target: 'li.player a.icon-tag',
        parent: 'ul#drop_list',
        beforeNext: function(){
          target.addClass('bind active');
        }
      }
```

Comment: Did you try `this.target`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a "JSON" object, but a JavaScript Object (or just "Object").  I assume that this is also contained in an Object literal as `obj: {` by itself is invalid syntax.

Anyway, yes you can reference properties of an object in methods with `this`.

```
beforeNext: function () {
    this.target;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Q9v8r/

Comment: @James Don't forget to turn it into a jQuery object, as it's not currently stored as one.

Comment: @crush Thanks guys, the full object is here: 

`options = {
    steps: [
        {
        target: 'li.player.playing .share-btns a.icon-tag',
        parent: 'ul#drop_list',
        ok:true,
        beforeNext: function(){
          this.target.addClass('blink active');
          $("a.icon-tag").bind('click', function() {
            tour.finish();
          });
        }
      }
  ]
};`

so `options` is an object with an array `steps` that contains a number of objects. `this.target` doesn't seem to be working, any ideas why?

Comment: @James `target` is just a string; try `$(this.target).addClass` as crush suggested

Answer (score 0):

In case you're dealing with plain JavaScript:

```
var cartoon = {"george jetson":{"son":"elroy","daughter":"judy"} }
```

Use the Object constructor to convert a string to an object:

```
cartoon["george jetson"].son = Object(cartoon["george jetson"].son)
```

Then bind the sibling value:

```
cartoon["george jetson"].son.sister = cartoon["george jetson"].daughter
```

And use `toString` to get the original value:

```
cartoon["george jetson"].son.toString()
```

**references**

- [Rosetta Code: Tree Traversal](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)
- [Finding list items in XHTML](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200211/msg00630.html)
- [Recursive tree traversal in level order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244930/1113772)
- [Big O of pre order traversal, in order traversal ,post order, level order for tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953496/1113772)