# Recursive tree traversal in level order

Tags: node.js, tree-traversal

I have the following recursive data structure and a method iterating over it. Whilst doing so it should add a unique number `n` to each node e.g. its respective number in [level order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_2) of the tree.

```
var data = {
    children: [
        { children: [ ... ] },
        { children: [ ... ] },
        { children: [ ... ] },
        ...
    ]
}

var process = function (node) {
    node.children.forEach(child, function () {
        process(child);
    });
    return node;
}
```

How can I achieve this without changes to the data structure and minimal changes to the processing function? Result of `process(data)` should be

```
var data = {
    n: 1
    children: [
        { n: 2, children: [ ... ] },
        { n: 3, children: [ ... ] },
        { n: 4, children: [ ... ] },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a queue to store nodes at each level. Use `null` to mark the end of one level.

Initially, push the root node and `null` to the queue. Then iterate the queue, push children of each node to the queue and mark non-null element. When you encounter a `null` element, push a new one. So two consequent `null` marks the end of iteration.

```
var process = function (node) {
    var queue = [node, null];
    var i = 0, n = 1;
    while (queue[i] != null || (i == 0 || queue[i-1] != null)) {
        if (queue[i] == null) {
            queue.push(null);
        }
        else {
            queue[i].n = n++;
            queue[i].children.forEach(function (elem) {
                queue.push(elem);
            });
        }
        i++;
    }
}

process(data);
console.log(data);
```

I used an Array for the queue and didn't dequeue the visited elements (**O(n)** space required). If the space consumed by `queue` is a bottleneck, you can replace it with some other queue implementation and alter the algorithm a bit.